# Enforcing Constraint Across Multiple One-to-Many Tables

Tags: mysql, constraints

I have the following (highly simplified) database schema:

[image: Simplified Database Schema]

In summary:

- An account has one user (one-to-one)
- An account has many projects (one-to-many)
- A project has multiple users (one-to-many)

My concern is that the user belongs to the project, and the project belongs to the account, yet using this schema *there's no way to guarantee that a user that belongs to an account also belongs to the account that belongs to a project.*

**My question is this:** Is there a way to use MySQL to add a constraint to ensure that the user that belongs to a project also belongs to the account that belongs to the project?

I'm using MySQL 5.1.56.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, thank you to Garcia Hurtado for the great feedback and opinions. It's definitely appreciated when someone in the community spends time and energy to provide thoughtful responses.

I ended up using a composite key to resolve this issue. You can see the schema using the following SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/0612b

It doesn't allow you to test it out with INSERT statements so you can simply download and install the database schema to try it out if you'd like.

The easiest test example is to use the following SQL statement:

```
INSERT INTO  project_users (user_id, account_id) VALUES (1, 2)
```

This will raise the following MySQL error:

```
#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

Answer (score 0):

> there's no way to guarantee that a user that belongs to an account also belongs to the account that belongs to a project.

Correct. But this isn't a limitation of MySQL, it is a limitation of your current schema. From what I see, you have created a 1-1 relationship from users > accounts, meaning that a user can only belong to one account under this schema. If your solution for this restrictive relationship is to have duplicate users in the same table, I'm afraid you have a highly denormalized schema, which will be the source of many headaches in the future.

I strongly suggest that you focus on modeling your business entities first (following at least 3NF) before attempting to institute constraints. To start with, it sounds like you need a many-to-many relationship between users and accounts (in order to accommodate the "user that belongs to an account, also needs to belong to another account" requirement)

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply, @Garcia Hurtado. I'll adjust the schema since it doesn't actually show that there's a unique email_address field in the users table. My bad for simplifying the diagram too much. I also modified the description to reflect this, too.

Comment: No. There's a one-to-one relationship between users and accounts. I modified the summary to reflect this since I noticed that my original description was also inaccurate.

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed you updated that portion too. In the updated problem domain, what I would suggest is that you don't actually need to have a link between users and accounts, given that you can get this relationship "indirectly" (via projects). This too is a denormalization that I would try to get rid of. Is that possible?

Comment: I agree it's de-normalized since there's obvious redundancy. It's an interesting thought experiment you've proposed. I'm looking at the entire schema and, at first glance at least, it looks like it would break some other business rules or simply push the de-normalization problem elsewhere. (One obvious concern is that a user doesn't have to belong to a project, but can still perform other actions in the system.)

Comment: I suppose I could use a trigger that could verify that the user belongs to the account. I really don't like that solution because it seems like a workaround. I'd rather solve it elegantly in the schema.

Comment: Consider this also: a user can belong to many projects, but only one account. Which one of those projects should be the one that guarantees a link between the user and the project's account? If I understand your business domain properly, this highlights another discrepancy in the schema, which is caused by the relationship between user and account. I still think removing that relationship is the easiest solution to your headaches.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I've drawn out several schemas to represent your ideas, including attaching a project to a user to an account, attaching a user to a project to an account, and several other variations to no meaningful avail. I think I'm leaning toward using a composite key on the users table for the user id and the account id. I'm not sure of what the knock on effects of this will be, but I'm happy to reply back if this works/doesn't work.